# Social media measurement with Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, social-media, metrics

I work for a non profit and we are currently trying to develop a system to measure and evaluate our social media channels (Facebook and Twitter).

We would like to track a variety of social metrics, including, but not limited to:

- Twitter

  - # of followers
  - # of mentions
  - # of retweets
- Facebook

  - # of likes
  - # people talking about
  - # of page views

We are currently using a paid platform for this. I wondered if there is a way to configure Google Analytics to do this?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Pro Webmasters as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: @JohnConde I've re-worded this question I trust it's of a more relevant format to be allowed back intot he discussion?

Answer (score 1):

Google Analytics can provide [interaction metrics on non-Google networks such as Facebook and Twitter fetched through sharing buttons placed on your website pages](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSocial) but cannot provide any metrics directly about your organizations's Facebook and Twitter pages.

There is a nice list of sites which provide Twitter analytics [here](http://www.razorsocial.com/free-twitter-analytics/)

While some of these tools don't capture your FB and Twitter password, they need you to authenticate using FB and Twitter via their site.